# JavaScript/jQuery reference to a third party website works locally, not when hosted on godaddy run site (404 error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-status-code-404, google-text-to-speech

I am beginning work on a web app that involves text-to-speech. Using a technique learned from youtube user Wes Bos, my code passes a random number through Google's english text-to-speech API (literally pasting it into the URL and returning the audio) each time a button is clicked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>SujiQ Dev.0</title>
       
 
   </head>
   
<body>

   <!--text display/button -->

        <p>generate random number</p>
  <div id="output1"></div>
  <button id="btn1" onclick="outText()">Random number</button>
 
 <!--Hidden audio player -->

        <audio src="" class="speech" hidden></audio>

<!--jQuery lib-->
       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<!--read number out loud each button click -->

       <script> 

/*displays random number-of-the-moment; called on button click */

  function outText() {
  

  var randNum = Math.round(Math.exp(Math.random()*Math.log(10000000-0+1))); /*that's more like it*/

  document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = randNum;

/* play audio of random number */

  $(function(){
        $("button#btn1").on("click",function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          
          
          var url = "https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=" + randNum + "&tl=en";

          $(".speech").attr("src", url).get(0).play();
 
 
        });
       });

  }
     
 
       </script>

 </body>
 
</html>
```

This code executes swimmingly without fail when run locally on my browser, but when hosting the exact same code on my godaddy provided site, the random number generator works but access to google's speech API almost always fails, returning a network console error along the lines of: "GET https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=152&tl=en 404 (Not Found)". Interestingly, once in a very blue moon, it goes through and reads the number out loud.

What gives? I've looked around but I'm stumped.

[[Edit]]
The code also fails to read the number out loud when run as a Stack Overflow snippet

Comment: I could make a comment about the quality of GoDaddy or lack thereof.  Try another host as a test.

Comment: Regarding your edit: your code is working fine for me as the StackOverflow snippet.  It's read aloud.

Comment: I see a mixture of `https` and `http` URLs in the same page.  That can sometimes cause problems.

Comment: @Sparky Do you have any recommendations? What do you use?

Comment: I get the same `GET https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=34&tl=en`  error when run in the above snippet, just to confirm

Comment: Doesn't the Google Translate API require an API key?

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the suggestion. I tried changing everything to 'https' - alas, the same 404 errors

Comment: hmmm it is interesting that people are getting different results from the snippet. 

@AlexanderO'Mara I don't believe so? The script runs no problem when dragged into my chrome browser

Comment: ["Google Translate API is available as a paid service. See the Pricing and FAQ pages for details."](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs) Although if that's the case, I'm not sure how it works at all.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara thanks for bringing this up. Maybe once the code is hosted google rejects any calls it unless the site is registered? I still find it odd that the code works locally then. Hmm

Comment: @marzipan you nailed it with your last comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a paid API. Youll need to set up your project on the [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/) then youll have to input your CC billing info. Once thats done, turn on the API under the APIs tab.

Then go to "Credentials". On the right hand side, click "Edit Settings", in the provided box, add the url to your domain where the file will be hosted like "http://mywebsite.com". **Dont** put the full address to the file like "http://mywebsite.com/mypage.html". Save your changes.

As for why your file works when run locally, below are the addresses to my test files:

**local file, run on a mac**

`file:///Volumes/Macintosh%20HD/Users/DoDSoftware/Desktop/soundTest.html`

**local file, run on a PC**

`file:///C:/Users/Flights%20Trainer/Desktop/soundTest.html`

hosted file

`http://affordable-glass.com/test/soundTest.html`

You see the `file:///` in front of the local files? I'd guess that Google has the API set up to allow all origins coming from `file:///` as they know those will be local files and not hosted files. This way, developers can test the api and create their apps before committing to a payment plan with them. But the of course they block any request originating from a hosted site that's not on a paid program with them.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I tried creating a new project on the Google developer console (I haven't used this before). It appears this is a paid service?

What I am gathering from your response and another comment is that one generally needs to pay for Google API use. If that is true, do you know why it is working when run locally? Does it only need to be paid when hosted?

Comment: When you say "run locally" do you mean from your actual html file or when you paste that url in a browser?

Comment: locally as dragging the html file from my disk into a browser

Comment: gotcha, I just tested that, same here, check out my edit above

Comment: Superb answer - thanks for making it so easy to understand! I'll keep testing "locally" then before committing to payment - really happy to know it was only a credentials issue.